# Bootstrap fonts folder

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am writing a seminar work about Twitter Bootstrap. I should implement a description of all files in the bootstrap file but I don't know what single files in fonts folder exactly do.

```
├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
    └── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
```

Is there anyone who could describe the usage of those 5 files?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are just different format of the Glyphicons font, to work with different browsers. See [this page](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/) for a handy explanation:

> This is the method with the deepest support possible right now:
>
> ```
> @font-face {
>   font-family: 'MyWebFont';
>   src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
>   src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
>        url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
>        url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
>        url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
>        url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
> }
> ```

See the [corresponding lines in the Bootstrap LESS source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/glyphicons.less#L11).

Comment: The OP asked for the usage of these files, and I also have this question. The above files are included in the zip file downloaded with the [basic bootstrap download](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download). It is clear what to do with the `css` and `js` files, but do these font files need to be included on the website? If so, where? If the `css` is stored under `public_html/css/bootstrap.css` and the `js` under `public_html/js/bootstrap.min.js` - where would one put these font files?

Comment: The default place that Bootstrap looks for those font files is in `../fonts`, relative to the CSS file URL. In your case, this means placing them in a `public_html/fonts/` directory. Does that help?

Comment: Very much, Greg; exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks tons for the reply. +1